# Set time for applying css in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my js code. Actually I want to set time to apply this css. I tried using setTimeout but not working. How to do using setTimeout or anything else. Please help. Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".front").click(function() {
    $(".flip-container").css({
      "height": "0px"
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: show how did you apply setTimeout

Comment: yes.. i added setTimeout(function() before $("flip-container")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)** as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".front").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".flip-container").css({
        "height": "0px"
      });
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

---

you can also do it with some animation using **[`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".front").click(function() {
    $(".flip-container").animate({
      "height": "0px"
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: You created demo while you haven't any element!

Comment: @Mohammad : just removed :)

Comment: ..nice..i used .animate instead of .css , it's giving nice animation. Thank you..

Comment: @sagarkodte : glad to help you :)